# Can connect my localhost webservice with emulator but can't with my mobile phone

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services, web

I just develop android app that that get and set data using a RESTful api and jdbc to connect the database that use MySQL. all work just fine when I'm using a localhost and connect with an emulator to the ip 10.0.2.2:8085.
when I try to connect with my mobie phone to the localhost I can't get the right ip, I tried using the 10.0.2.2 of the emulator ip and also I tried to use ipconfig command to get my ipv4 adress and use it but it also didn't work.
I am using a TP-Link router as a WAN that connect 2 computer(the wirless is not working).
Hope that someone know this issue :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*You Must be on same network while using localhost server connection*.

It might be the case that your computer is connected to TP-Link router network and your mobile is connected to your sim card network.

There is one more possibility that your firewall might be blocking your ip accessing from another device. so just check that also.